# Xamarin Android : "Bundle assemblies into native code" throw error on TFS build server

Tags: android, tfs, xamarin, build

I got this error when I build Xamarin Android solution on TFS build server with project option "Bundle assemblies into native code" enabled :

> "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets (1991):
>   Missing Android NDK toolchains directory '\toolchains'. Please install
>   the Android NDK."

I checked Visual Studio Xamarin options on server and NDK path is defined correctly.

Comment: Can you try the following, regarding `MakeBundleNativeCodeExternal`? https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/166699/#Comment_166699

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting error with Release build, please try below method mentioned by *David Howard*

> Fixed: As an update if anyone else having this problem when building
> Release (that the NDK \toolchains is missing) it appears that mkbundle
> is broken.
>
> The root cause is that "MakeBundleNativeCodeExternal" is true for
> release and false for Debug. Although this appears as a licensing
> issue, my build agent has an Enterprise licence installed.
>
> Disabling "MakeBundleNativeCodeExternal" in Release build by editing
> the Android project in notepad, seach for 'BundleAssemblies' - and
> change the 'True' under Release configuration section to ' False'
> save, build Release, works
>
> Source: [Missing Android NDK toolchains directory](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/7871/missing-android-ndk-toolchains-directory)

Comment: Thank you for your response, but in my case I want this option enabled. It's to increase the code obfuscation.